# Properties of saturation function

Tags: functions

Define the saturation function $\mathrm{sat}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [\underline{u}\;\overline{u}]\subset \mathbb{R}$ as:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{sat}(x)=\begin{cases}
\underline{u}\qquad & \mathrm{if}\;x<\underline{u} \\
\overline{u}\qquad & \mathrm{if}\;x>\overline{u}\\
x\qquad & \mathrm{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and let $K>0$. I was wondering if it is true the following:

$$
c:=\left[\mathrm{sat}(x-Ky)-\mathrm{sat}(x)\right]y<0,
$$
for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

If it is, how to prove it without analyzing all the cases? More in general, is it possible to define general arithmetic properties for such a function?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean
$$
\left[\mathrm{sat}(x-Ky)-\mathrm{sat}(x)\right]y\leq0,
$$
as we can have $y=0$.

Yes this is true.  Note that as $K>0$ it is equivalent to:
$$
\left[\mathrm{sat}(x-Ky)-\mathrm{sat}(x)\right]Ky\leq0,
$$
which for $y\neq 0$ is equivalent to:
$$
\frac{\left[\mathrm{sat}(x)-\mathrm{sat}(x-Ky)\right]}{Ky}\geq0,
$$
as $(Ky)^2\geq 0$.
This is just the statement that $\mathrm{sat}(x)$ is a non-decreasing function, which is true.